# pre_delete signal not working in specific directory

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, signals

i want remove file from storage when a `File` instance removed.trying to use django signal. here is my model File:

```
class File(models.Model):
    orig_name = models.CharField(_('Original Name'), max_length=255)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey('conversation.Conversation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the architecture of every app are same.means all of app have own `signals` directory and in signals's directory we have `__init__.py`  and `handlers.py` files .here is a brief tree of my app with some detail for `file`'s app:

```
 apps
    ├── conversation
    ├── post    
    └── file
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── signals
        │   ├── handlers.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── views.py
```

here is `apps/file/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FileConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.file' # exact as INSTALLED_APP in setting.py

    def ready(self):
        import apps.file.signals.handers
```

here is `apps/file/signals/handlers.py` :

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from apps.file.models import File


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=File)
def remove_file_from_storage(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
      print('pre_delete signal for File working')
      # some code is here
```

and `app/file/signals/__init__.py` file is empty. in this project we are using multiple signals and all of them working fine but i don't know why this signal not working.other signal are from custom and build-in signal both. please notice when i moving `def remove_file_from_storage` function into other app into related `app_name/signals/handlers.py` it's working fine.the process of deleting is a simple `generics.DestroyAPIView` of DRF. where is the problem with my architect of using signal?thank you

Comment: Hi @mehdi, could you provide your `apps.py` file also?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo thank you for reply. question updated with `apps/file/apps.py` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you use `receiver` decorator to register signals. With that you have to place your code inside ready function of your Django application. [This document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver) does mention about that:

> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are connected in the ready() method of your application configuration class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, simply import the signals submodule inside ready().

But in real practice, we won't put all signals code inside `ready` method, that might make our code harder to read and harder to maintain. So like you did, we will put the signals inside `signals.py` and then load it into your app via `ready` method, like so:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FileConfig(AppConfig):
    label = 'file'
    name = 'file'

    def ready(self):
        from apps.file import signals  # NOQA
        # add # NOQA to ignore error message from Python linter when we just import but never used
```

and set this to `__init__.py` so that Django could discover your app:

```
 apps
    ├── conversation
    ├── post    
    └── file
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── __init__.py # Add to this file
        ├── models.py
        ├── signals
        │   ├── handlers.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── views.py
```

```py
default_app_config = 'apps.file.apps.FileConfig'
```

You could also take a look at [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) to gain more details about Django signals

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for help. i do that but still my signal not calling in `apps/file/signals/handlers.puy` with code that i put in my question and i don't know why?(i'm updating my question by your hint so if you have any idea let me know)

Comment: Have you checked that the ready method was called? You could take a look at the article I have embedded inside the answer, inside `__init__.py` of file module, you could add this line to make sure that you app loaded correctly: `default_app_config='apps.file.apps.FileConfig'`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications-ref

Comment: `default_app_config = 'apps.klass.apps.ClassConfig'` exists in `klass` app. exactly when i putting my signal's function into this app(into signals directory) it's working but out of this `klass` app it's not working.what i need to do now?adding all of my signal into this app?!sry if i'm too much noob :(

Comment: you add the same on your `file` app. I will update my answer